# how to install and configure gitweb in opensuse?

Tags: opensuse, gitweb

when i run "zypper install gitweb" , it returns :

```
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'gitweb' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'gitweb' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

And also zypper se gitweb shows "No packages found." 
My  openSUSE version is 11.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to install the package `git-web`?